# Changing field of an object that stored on a list that is on different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, thread-safety

So I have two threads, Thread A and B. Thread A contains an ArrayList that has my objects. What I want to do is that: on Thread B, creating new object and adding it to that list. Then changing that object's field on Thread A. After that, read that changed field on Thread B. But sadly, when I read it on Thread B, I get the default value that created on object constructor. So, how can I read new that value?

### UPDATE

**Some info: onEnable method executed on application start by the API I use called "Bukkit", Everything bound to Bukkit executed on Thread A which is Bukkit's main thread**

Main.class:

```
private static ExecutorService executorService;
private static List<Confirmation> confirmations;

public void onEnable() {
    executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    confirmations = new ArrayList<>();
}

public static ExecutorService getExecutorService() {
    return executorService;
}

public static Confirmation createConfirmation(CommandSender sender, String command, String[] args) {
    removeConfirmation(sender, command);
    Confirmation confirmation = new Confirmation(sender, command, args);
    confirmations.add(confirmation);
    return confirmation;
}

public static void removeConfirmation(CommandSender commandSender, String command) {
    confirmations.removeIf(confirmation -> confirmation.getSender().getName().equals(commandSender.getName()) && confirmation.getCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(command));
}

public static Confirmation getConfirmation(CommandSender commandSender, String command) {
    return confirmations.stream().filter(confirmation -> confirmation.getSender().getName().equals(commandSender.getName()) && confirmation.getCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(command)).findFirst().orElse(null);
}

public static Confirmation createConfirmationIfNull(CommandSender commandSender, String command, String[] args) {
    Confirmation confirmation = getConfirmation(commandSender, command);
    return confirmation != null ? confirmation : createConfirmation(commandSender, command, args);
}
```

Confirmation.class:

```
private final CommandSender sender;
private final String command;
private final String[] args;
private boolean confirmed;

public Confirmation(CommandSender sender, String command, String[] args) {
    this.sender = sender;
    this.command = command;
    this.args = args;
    this.confirmed = false;
}

public CommandSender getSender() {
    return sender;
}

public String getCommand() {
    return command;
}

public String[] getArgs() {
    return args;
}

public boolean isConfirmed() {
    return confirmed;
}

public void setConfirmed(boolean bln) {
    this.confirmed = bln;
}
```

Command.class:

```
@CommandHandler(name = "rank", usage = "/rank <set|prefix>", requiredRank = Rank.ADMINISTRATOR)
public void rank(CommandSender sender, Command command, String s, String[] args) { //Always called on Thread A
    String str = args[0];
    RankCommandAction action = Arrays.stream(RankCommandAction.values()).filter(rankCommandAction -> rankCommandAction.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(str)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    if (action == null) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Usage: /rank <set|prefix>");
        return;
    }

    Main.getExecutorService().submit(() -> action.getConsumer().accept(sender, args)); //Thread B
}

private enum RankCommandAction {

    SET_PREFIX("prefix", (CommandSender sender, String[] args) -> {
        CommandConfirmationEvent event = new CommandConfirmationEvent(sender, "rank", args, ChatColor.RED + "Are you sure?");
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().callEvent(event);

        if (!event.isCancelled()) {
            sender.sendMessage("Prefix changed");
        }
    }),


    SET_RANK("set", (CommandSender sender, String[] args) -> {
        CommandConfirmationEvent event = new CommandConfirmationEvent(sender, "rank", args, ChatColor.RED + "Are you sure?");
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().callEvent(event);

        if (!event.isCancelled()) {
            sender.sendMessage("Changed rank");
        }
    });
```

CommandConfirmationEvent.class:

```
private final CommandSender commandSender;
private final String command;
private final String[] args;

private final Confirmation confirmation;
private String warningMessage;

public CommandConfirmationEvent(CommandSender commandSender, String command, String[] args, String warningMessage) {
    this.commandSender = commandSender;
    this.command = command;
    this.args = args;
    this.warningMessage = warningMessage;
    this.confirmation = Main.createConfirmationIfNull(commandSender, command, args);
}

public CommandSender getCommandSender() {
    return commandSender;
}

public String getCommand() {
    return command;
}

public String[] getArgs() {
    return args;
}

public Confirmation getConfirmation() {
    return confirmation;
}

public String getWarningMessage() {
    return warningMessage;
}

public void setWarningMessage(String warningMessage) {
    this.warningMessage = warningMessage;
}

@Override
public boolean isCancelled() {
    return this.confirmation != null && !this.confirmation.isConfirmed();
}
```

This is what literally executed when calling the event:

```
if (!event.getConfirmation().isConfirmed()) {
    event.getCommandSender().sendMessage("Please confirm");
    return;
}
Main.removeConfirmation(event.getConfirmation());
```

And lastly, this is the command to confirm (on Thread A):

```
@CommandHandler(name = "confirm")
public void confirm(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String str, String[] args) { //Always called on Thread A
    Confirmation confirmation = findConfirmation(sender, "confirm", args);

    if (confirmation != null) {
        confirmation.setConfirmed(true);
        String[] arg = confirmation.getArgs();
        Bukkit.dispatchCommand(sender, confirmation.getCommand() + (arg != null && arg.length > 0 ? " " + StringUtils.merge(arg, " ") : "")); //This runs the "rank" command again
        Main.removeConfirmation(confirmation);
    }
}

private Confirmation findConfirmation(CommandSender sender, String[] args) {
    List<Confirmation> list = Main.getConfirmations(sender);

    if (list.isEmpty())
        return null;

    Confirmation confirmation;
    if (list.size() > 1) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Since you have multiple confirmations awaiting, you must specify the confirmation you want to confirm.");
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Usage: /confirm <command>");
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Awaiting confirmations: " + StringUtils.merge(list.stream().map(Confirmation::getCommand).toArray(String[]::new), ", ") + ".");
            return null;
        } else {
            Confirmation foundConfirmation = list.stream().filter(confirmation1 -> confirmation1.getCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(args[0])).findFirst().orElse(null);
            if (foundConfirmation == null) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You don't have any confirmations for the command '" + args[0] + "'.");
                return null;
            } else {
                confirmation = foundConfirmation;
            }
        }
    } else {
        confirmation = list.get(0);
    }

    return confirmation;
}
```

Comment: don't use an `ArrayList` to begin with when using multiple threads; unless you employ some sort of synchronization

Comment: I used CopyOnWriteArrayList and Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList()) but both didn't seem to work either

Comment: and we need to guess your code? can you provide a minimal, reproducible example may be?

Comment: added an example code

Comment: this `This prints "NAME"` does not happen in my case, when I ran this. where is the _reproducible_ part?

Comment: You know what, giving example was an horrible idea, I will just post the original code

Comment: Just posted the whole thing, hope you understand what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: I was removing the object from the list on confirm command, and it removes the object before running the "rank" command again. That causes the second "rank" command execution to not find the confirmation object.

Answer (score 0):

### Issues

1. As per the given code, it can likely throw IndexOutOfBounds exception at this line `objects.get(0).setName("TEST");`

### Reason

1. The task submitted to executor service will run on its own timeline (inaddition to sleep `1000`)
2. Main thread sleeping for `200` is not going to help (even increasing to `2000` may not help deterministically)

### What should be done

1. Create two CountDown Latches
2. Pass one latch to the submitted task
3. after setting it, it will count down on the latch and will wait on other latch
4. the main will wait on the latch that will be count down by task
5. main thread, once notified from task thread, will do the update and countdown on other latch
6. Now task will be notified and will print the updated value

```java
    static class MyObject {
        volatile String value;
        MyObject(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        CountDownLatch updateLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch addLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            objects.add(new MyObject("NAME"));
            try {
                addLatch.countDown();
                updateLatch.await();
                System.out.println(objects.get(0).value); //This prints "NAME"
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });


        try {
            addLatch.await();
            objects.get(0).value = "TEST";
            updateLatch.countDown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting me but like I said, the code above is just an example and the thing is it prints "TEST" with no errors. My original code is similar to it (except sleeps and stuff) and it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

You should use the same object instance on both threads, and syncronize them when accessing this object.

There is no meaning in your description "Thread A contains an Arraylist". If it's a local variable, Thread B can never access it.

Comment: What I meant is that the list is static and created on Thread A (see my example code)